# SSL with Haproxy dont shows CSS

Tags: ssl, server, haproxy

I have a Problem with my HaProxy

```
global
    log /dev/log    local0
    log /dev/log    local1 notice
    chroot /var/lib/haproxy
    stats socket /run/haproxy/admin.sock mode 660 level admin
    stats timeout 30s
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
    daemon
    maxconn 2048
    tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048

    # Default SSL material locations
    #ca-base /etc/haprorxy/certs/ca_bundle.crt
    #crt-base /etc/haproxy/certs/certificate.crt

    # Default ciphers to use on SSL-enabled listening sockets.
    # For more information, see ciphers(1SSL). This list is from:
    #  https://hynek.me/articles/hardening-your-web-servers-ssl-ciphers/
    #ssl-default-bind-ciphers ECDH+AESGCM:DH+AESGCM:ECDH+AES256:DH+AES256:ECDH+AES128:DH+AES:ECDH+3DES:DH+3DES:RSA+AESGCM:RSA+AES:RSA+3DES:!aNULL:!MD5:!DSS
    #ssl-default-bind-options no-sslv3

defaults
    log global
    mode    tcp
    option  httplog
    option  dontlognull
        option forwardfor
        option http-server-close
    retries 3
    option redispatch
    timeout connect 5s
        timeout client  5s
        timeout server  5s
    errorfile 400 /etc/haproxy/errors/400.http
    errorfile 403 /etc/haproxy/errors/403.http
    errorfile 408 /etc/haproxy/errors/408.http
    errorfile 500 /etc/haproxy/errors/500.http
    errorfile 502 /etc/haproxy/errors/502.http
    errorfile 503 /etc/haproxy/errors/503.http
    errorfile 504 /etc/haproxy/errors/504.http

frontend http_front
   bind *:80
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ http
   stats uri /haproxy?stats
   default_backend wp7.xxxx.com
   stats auth admin:test

frontend https_front
   mode tcp
   bind *:443 ssl crt /etc/haproxy/certs/wp7.xxxxx.com.pem
   reqadd X-Forwarded-Proto:\ https
   default_backend wp7.xxxxxxx.com
   stats uri /haproxy?stats
   stats auth admin:test

backend wp7.xxxx.com
   redirect scheme https if !{ ssl_fc }
   option httpclose
   option forwardfor
   balance roundrobin
   server Backend Backend_IP:80 check
   #server rproxy02 xx.xx.xxx.xx:443 check
```

But the Website doesn`t look like how it should on https: https://www.pic-upload.de/view-32841877/Untitled.png.html

This is how it should look like: https://www.pic-upload.de/view-32841910/Untitled.png.html

The Website should run a Wordpress installation. When I go through port 80 (http) everything is ok, but If I go through Port 443 (https like on the picture), it looks like in the Picture.

Can someone help or have an idea?

Comment: Please post the images directly, URLs might be down at some point and stop been useful to others.

Comment: Try going to the image url directly.  It may give you an actual error message or log something useful

Comment: My guess is that it is not related to haproxy but because you access the site with https but the CSS is still loaded with http, i.e. mixed content. Unfortunately it is impossible to be sure based on only the images you show. But check the developer console for error messages that it does not load a specific content.

Comment: If I am using a nginx rProxy it works...

Answer (score 0):

```
http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
http-request add-header X-Forwarded-Proto https if { ssl_fc }
```

try these lines in frontend

https://serversforhackers.com/c/using-ssl-certificates-with-haproxy

Got same issue and resolved by this link. Hope this could help.